# How to convert this non-deterministic FSA to a deterministic one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

wondering how to convert this non-deterministic FSA

[image: Initial Problem]

to a deterministic one, specifically the tables.

I have got this so far but am stuck:

[image: Try]

How do i assign BHMQ? For state one, won't there be four digits? (C, I, N, R)?

Comment: make a new state {B,H,M,Q} as S, then S(0) = B(0) + H(0) + M(0) + Q(0) and then do it for S(1). And continue adding states till no new state is reached

Comment: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/compilers/slides/LexicalPart3.pdf this pdf may help. Check this once

Comment: I am confused @KishanKumar, how would that look on the table?

Comment: the states in the newly constructed dfa should not necessarily be same as the in nfa. You could consider state BHMQ as a single state and use it

Comment: And in table write the new state in the place of BHMQ, and make a new row for that state Only. Make row for tables of only the states which are derived by the start state in DFA

Comment: @KishanKumar might not have removed the nulls correctly, any pdfs on how to do that properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120670/converting-epsilon-nfa-to-nfa see this for e-transition

Comment: @KishanKumar Is there a way to do this purely based off the tables?

Comment: yeah, you can do it. By only using tables.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is the so-called [power set construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction). From the initial automaton, the state set is converted by taking its power set, which is the set of all of its subsets, to be the the state set of the resulting automaton; the final states are the ones which contain at least one of the initial final states.

The resulting automaton is equivalent to the initial one in the sense that the accepted languages are equal. However, the number of states may grow exponentially.